# split '{a}{b}{c}'?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I have an object that looks like

```
var obj = {
   a: {
      a: {
         a: 'value'
      }
   },
   b: {
      a: {
         a: 'value2'
      },
      b: {
         a: 'value3'
      }
   }
}
```

I have a function which gets given a mask that looks like `{b}{a}{a}` what I want to do is get the value at `obj.b.a.a` how can I do this?

Comment: There's no value at `obj.a.b.c`... ;-)

Comment: Can you clarify the question?  obj.a.b will be undefined, since there is no "b" property of the obj.a object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slice off the first and last character, split by `}{`, and then recursively access the object with each element in turn (since `foo.bar` and `foo['bar']` are equivalent).

Comment: Awesome :) using
`mask = mask.substr(1).substr(0, mask.length-2).split('}{');`
var arr = obj;
 for(var i in mask)
            arr = arr[mask[i]];`

Answer (score 2):

This will work if your mask always has three properties. If not, you can write a function that does something similar:

```
var mask = "{a}{b}{c}";
var props = mask.replace(/{|}/g, "");

obj[props[0]][props[1]][props[2]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
obj.getMask = function(s) {
  var o=this, attrs=s.slice(1,s.length-1).split("\}\{");
  while (attrs.length > 0) {
    o = o[attrs.shift()];
    if (!o) return null;
  }
  return o;
};
obj.getMask("{a}{a}{a}"); // => "value"
obj.getMask("{b}{a}{a}"); // => "value1"
obj.getMask("{x}{y}{z}"); // => null
```

Of course, you can change the signature to pass in "obj" instead of using `this` if you don't want to muck up the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` rather than use recursion. Here's a one-liner:

```
function index(obj, indexList) {
    return indexList.reduce(function(obj,x){return obj[x]}, obj);
}

function indexWithMask(mask) {
    return index(obj, mask.slice(1,-1).split('}{'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code without using `eval`. Its easy to understand too.

```
function value(obj, props) {
  if (!props) return obj;
  var propsArr = props.split('.');
  var prop = propsArr.splice(0, 1);
  return value(obj[prop], propsArr.join('.'));
}

var obj = { a: { b: '1', c: '2', d:{a:{b:'blah'}}}};

console.log(value(obj, 'a.d.a.b')); //returns blah
```

If you are still using the mask part, you can modify a bit on the code.

```
function value(obj, props) {
    if (!props) return obj;
    var propsArr = props.match(/\{[a-zA-Z1-9]+\}/g);
    var prop = propsArr.splice(0, 1);
    return value(obj[prop[0].replace('{', '').replace('}', '')], propsArr.join(''));
}
```